# How do I refresh the current route when arguments change?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-web

I'm using [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) with some arguments as url parameters. If I push the same route as the one I'm currently on, but using different parameters, then the displayed widget is not updated.

Why not? Can I force it to update or is there a setting for auto_route to detect these changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `auto_route` treats route name as its key. You can change that behavior with the `usePathAsKey` argument in the `*Route` class:

| Property | Default value | Definition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| usePathAsKey | false | if true path is used as page key instead of name |

[source](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library#materialroute--cupertinoroute--adaptiveroute--customroute)

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to set this globally for all routes?

Comment: I don't see such an option for the whole router. Looks like you'd need to pass that parameter to all routes that you want to replace on the stack like that. You can also create an issue in auto_route repository to ask the author or one of the contributors for such option.

Comment: For anyone else stumbling across this: My confusion was in using nested routes, because it's not enough to set `usePathAsKey` for the parent route.

Comment: Life savior for sure.